# MDB creation In WAS 7

Tags: queue, websphere-7, message-driven-bean

I am trying to create a local queue and a mdb that listens this local queue in my WAS 7.0 server. I reffered this [URL](http://thomasmodeneis.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/cc-creating-mdb-project-step-by-step-using-rsa-8-and-websphere-6-1_.pdf) and followed all the steps given. When i tried to run it am getting the below exception.

`AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl merge Caught exception while merging 
                                 com.ibm.wsspi.amm.merge.MergeException: expected reference with name jms/messageQueue to be a message destination reference
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.merge.ejb.ResourceMergeAction.getMessageDestinationRefData(ResourceMergeAction.java:245)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.merge.ejb.ResourceMergeAction.getResourceData(ResourceMergeAction.java:407)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.merge.ejb.ResourceMergeAction.mergeFieldTarget(ResourceMergeAction.java:174)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.amm.merge.AbstractMergeAction.merge(AbstractMergeAction.java:338)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.merge(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:159)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.commonarchive.AnnotationsProcessorImpl.merge(AnnotationsProcessorImpl.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.processAnnotations(WARFileImpl.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getStandardDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EARFileImpl.java:676)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleRefImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(ModuleRefImpl.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleRefImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(ModuleRefImpl.java:223)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.open(DeployedModuleImpl.java:249)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.initialize(DeployedModuleImpl.java:474)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.initializeModule(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.initialize(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:608)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.initialize(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.initializeApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2045)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:385)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:328)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:599)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:561)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1184)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1333)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1226)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:239)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:564)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:354)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.controller.InformationController.processForwardConfig(InformationController.java:217)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)`

When i searched in google it's ask me run a fix pack 29 from IBM, Please guide me is this really require to run this fix pack or we can solve this issue using server config change or please give me a procedure to create a MDB that uses local queue to post and listen a message.Below are my RSA info:

1. RAS 7.5.5
2. WAS 7.0

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your application server (or application) is misconfigured - jms/messageQueue is not message destination reference. This name is probably encountered when parsing annotations on your classes.

When configuring the server you should configure Connection factory, Queue and Activation spec to match the annotations in your code. Additionally don't forget to set proper resource references in your deployment descriptors.